# Using QGIS to access data delivered by ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, map-service

Can I use QGIS to access data delivered using ArcGIS Server?

The following servers don't seem to be compatible with QGIS

http://www.topofthesouthmaps.co.nz

​http://gis.wcrc.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services

Answer (score 7):

As of QGIS 2.16, ArcGIS MapServers and FeatureServers are natively supported. The icons are stacked with the Add WMS and Add WFS icons, respectively.

---

As of autumn 2015, there is a plugin to connect to the ArcGIS proprietary feature protocol, called the [ArcGIS REST API Connector](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/connector/). It's available in the main plugin repository, marked as experimental, with source code at the link I provided.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the [ArcGIS for Server map services have been exposed as a WMS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004pr000000) (which is a matter of its administrator ticking a checkbox) then you will be able to add them as  [WMS layers to QGIS](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/05/tutorial-using-online-data-via-wms-in.html).

The second service URL that you provided looks like it comes from ArcGIS for Server but neither looks like a WMS.  I recommend you contact their providers and request a WMS service URL.  Hopefully, this may be a simple request for them to fulfil.